# Perfect forwarding of pair.second using a lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, perfect-forwarding

Why this snippet doesn't compile?

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace vw = std::ranges::views;

int main()
{
    auto get_second = [](auto&& pair) constexpr noexcept -> decltype(auto)
                      { return std::forward<decltype(pair)>(pair).second; };
    
    std::unordered_map<unsigned, std::pair<double, char> > m = {{5, {0., 'a'}}};
    

    for (auto& [d, c] : m | vw::transform(get_second))
        c = 'b';

    for (auto const& pair : m)
        std::printf("(%u, (%.3f, %c))\n", pair.first, pair.second.first, pair.second.second);
}
```

The error, using gcc is:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:16:53: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'std::pair<double, char>&' to an rvalue of type 'std::__success_type<std::pair<double, char> >::type' {aka 'std::pair<double, char>'}
   16 |     for (auto& [d, c] : m | vw::transform(get_second))
      |                                                     ^
```

Shouldn't `-> decltype(auto)` resolve to `std::pair<double, char>&`? If I replace `-> decltype(auto)` by `-> std::pair<double, char>&` it works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Shouldn't `-> decltype(auto)` evaluate to `std::pair<double, char>&`?

No. Here's a much simpler example:

```cpp
struct X {
    int i;
};

X x{42};
decltype(auto) i = x.i;
```

Is `i` an `int` or an `int&`? It's an `int`. `decltype(auto)` derives its type by applying `decltype(...)` to the right-hand side. `decltype(x.i)` just gives you the type of the member, that's `int`.

In order to get an `int&` you have to do:

```cpp
decltype(auto) i = (x.i);
```

Because *now* we get the type as `decltype((x.i))`, which yields `int&`.

`decltype` has a [special rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) for unparenthesized access - so adding parentheses sidesteps it. This is why `decltype(x.i)` and `decltype((x.i))` can differ. Once we sidestep that one, `decltype` on an lvalue of type `T` yields the type `T&`. `x.i` is an lvalue of type `int`, so we get `int&`.

Note that I said *can* differ and not *must* differ, if the member `i` were of type `int&`, then both `decltype(x.i)` and `decltype((x.i))` would be `int&`.

---

Going back to the original example, you have the choice of doing either parenthesizing the returned expression (and dropping the unnecessary `constexpr`):

```cpp
auto get_second = [](auto&& pair) noexcept -> decltype(auto)
                  { return (FWD(pair).second); };
```

Or just knowing that because we're doing class member access, this will never be a prvalue, so we can simplify to using `auto&&` (without the need for additional parentheses):

```cpp
auto get_second = [](auto&& pair) noexcept -> auto&&
                  { return FWD(pair).second; };
```

---

Also the standard library itself comes with shorthands for this:

```cpp
for (auto& [d, c] : m | vw::transform(get_second))
```

You can instead write:

```cpp
for (auto& [d, c] : m | vw::values)
```

(or also `elements<1>`, in case you need other elements).

---

Lastly, the typical choice for a short name for the views namespace is `rv` (rather than `vw`). Or just use `views`.

Comment: Why `constexpr` offers nothing? `pair` has `constexpr` constructors, which means the lambda could receive `constexpr` objects of type `pair` right?

Comment: OMG you made my day with `values`. Thanks.

Comment: @Peregring-lk Lambdas are constexpr by default, you don't have to write anything.